# Mark as Read for a page in Django

Tags: python, django

I followed Sentdex Django tutorials to build a simple website. Now I want to add mark as read for each tutorial. See the image attached. Can you suggest how should I approach?

```
class blogCategory(models.Model):
    blog_category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField (upload_to ='static/images/models')
    category_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_category

class blogSeries(models.Model):
    blog_series = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField (upload_to ='static/images/models')
    blog_category = models.ForeignKey(blogCategory, default=1, verbose_name = "Category", on_delete = models.SET_DEFAULT)
    series_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Series"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_series

class blog(models.Model):
    completed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField (upload_to ='static/images/models',blank=True)
    blog_contents = models.TextField(default="")
    blog_publishedDate = models.DateTimeField("Date Published",default=datetime.now())
    blog_series = models.ForeignKey(blogSeries, default=1, verbose_name="Series", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    blog_slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwYmB.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you need to do some database and view shenenigans, first off you'll have to check if every page of your specific Tutorial received a `GET` method from the specific user, that is quite simple, then you'll have to update your `blog` model to not show `completed` as a **Boolean** but to actually store the users that have read that tutorial completely, that can be done by creating a `m2m` relationship to your `User` model and then afterwards checking if the **user** is present in that field to see if the **user** has read your tutorial.

The better approach would probably be to create each tutorial **page** as an object with a `m2m` field called something like `read_by` and reference a `blog` for it in a `ForeignKey` relationship, then everytime a user is accessing the `view` that is tied to that page do something like this:

```
def tutorial_page(request, pk):
    page = Page.objects.get(pk=pk) # query the page
    blog = page.tutorial # get the tutorial the page belongs to
    if request.method == 'GET':
        page.read_by.add(request.user)
        page.save()
        for page in blog.page_set.all() # loop through each page of the tutorial to see if they are all read 
            if request.user not in page.read_by.all():
                break # if one of the pages isn't read break the loop
            else:
                blog.read_by.add(request.user) # add the user to the *read_by* field in the *blog*
                blog.save()
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'page': page})
```

In this `view` when the `request.user` is accessing the page the block of code under the `if request.method == 'GET'` line is being executed, I commented the code so you could understand it.